# JPA: How to not commit an EntityTransaction

Tags: java, jpa

Let's say I have a scheduled job that regularly runs a database modification over a list of entities, all in one transaction. Depending on the situation, there might be lots to modify, or nothing at all.

```java
entityManager.getTransation().begin();

for (MyEntity e : myEntityRepository.getAllDirtyEntities()) {
    myEntityRepository.cleanUp(e); // does some modification to e
}

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

What is the best way to deal with scenarios where `getAllDirtyEntities()` returns nothing (= an empty `List`)?

1. `commit()` anyway, even though nothing was changed
2. `rollback()`, even though nothing was changed
3. neither of the two: do nothing; let the `entityTransaction` get GC'd
4. Avoid this scenario completely: query first, `begin()` & `commit()` the transaction only if there is something to do

Answer (score 0):

I'd say performance-wise 3. is the best option but it might eat up memory depending on the implementation and frequency of the run.
So, I'd go for 1. because it is the safest next-best performance option. 2. is probably slower und 4. is definitely slower.